# How to customize json_serializable library code generation?

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I use [json_serializable](https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable) library and firebase for database. I need to serialize and deserialize my data class to/from JSON. But firebase json format looks like this

```
{
  'some_id_here': {
     'title': 'some_title',
     'content': 'some_content',
     'timestamp': 'some_timestamp'
   }, ...
}
```

Here's my class

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'update.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()

class Update {
  final String id, title, content, timestamp;

  Update({this.id, this.title, this.content, this.timestamp});

  factory Update.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UpdateFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return _$UpdateToJson(this);
  }
}
```

So how to customize the toJson() function so I can deserialize from

```
Update('ID', 'TITLE', 'CONTENT', 'TIMESTAMP');
```

to

```
{
  'ID': {
     'title': 'TITLE',
     'content': 'CONTENT',
     'timestamp': 'TIMESTAMP'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 class ID {
  String title;
  String content;
  String timestamp;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> ID = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    ID['title'] = this.title;
    ID['content'] = this.content;
    ID['timestamp'] = this.timestamp;
    return ID;
  }
}
```

Comment: Because the returned json is not list of object. Should I use ```Map<String, ID> id;``` ??